# Android: Select ListView Items and get the Objects

Tags: android, listview

i made a custom listView having two textViews..for example student name and roll no...
now i want to implement a selection...for example..i will click on few students in the listview and the object should get saved somewhere ...for example:

```
        ClassList.add(new StudentList(99,"student1","code"));
        ClassList.add(new StudentList(70,"student2","code"));
        ClassList.add(new StudentList(20,"student3","code"));
        ClassList.add(new StudentList(30,"student4","code"));

        adapter = new StudentListViewAdapter(this, ClassList,"code");
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now i should be able to set another method for example:

```
ClassList2=listView.getSelectedStudents();
```

this should return the selected students..for example if i select student 1,student 2 it should return Student List Objects for both of them so i can access there roll and Code too
And there is another problem...when i deselect it should remove that object from the list..
It would be really helpfull if someone will write a sample code

This is how i do it..but i don't think it is really a good method

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (ItemView == null) {
        ItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customvistview_atd, parent, false);
    }

    //find the hotels to work with
    final studentlist currentList = totalClass_list.get(position);

    //fill the view
    final TextView textview_studentName = (TextView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_atd_studentName);
    textview_studentName.setText((currentList.getName()));

    final TextView textview_studentRollno = (TextView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_atd_studentRollno);
    textview_studentRollno.setText((currentList.getRoll_no() + ""));

    final CardView cardView = (CardView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_atd);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            for (i = 0; i < presentStudents.size(); i++) {
                if (presentStudents.get(i).getMindex() == position) {
                    System.out.println("m-index : "+presentStudents.get(i).getMindex());
                    System.out.println("position : "+position);
                    isChecked = true;
                    System.out.println("I am in the loop, I am at position: "+i);
                    me = i;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (isChecked) {
                presentStudents.remove(me);
                isChecked = false;
                ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#198b9f")), new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)};
                TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
                cardView.setBackground(trans);
                trans.startTransition(1500);

                textview_studentName.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                textview_studentName.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

                //cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                System.out.println("I am in isChecked");
            } else {
                presentStudents.add(new tempclass(currentList.getRoll_no(),atdCode,position));


                ColorDrawable[] colorCard = {new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#198b9f"))};
                TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(colorCard);
                cardView.setBackground(trans);
                trans.startTransition(1500);

                textview_studentName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textview_studentName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
             //   cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                System.out.println("I am in else, making it blue");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: what you have try so far?

Comment: you can try using a contextual action bar, where you can implement the methods in it to implement your functionality. refer here http://www.technotalkative.com/contextual-action-bar-cab-android/

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            StudentLists studentList = listView.getItemAtPosition(i);//selected object   
            adapter.dismiss(); // If you want to close the adapter
        }
    });
```